# INSERT INTO suppliers casue Schema Creation Failed: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: sql, oracle

> What's causing this error?
>
> Schema Creation Failed: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

.........................

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers 
    (
         sid int, 
         sname varchar(20), 
         address varchar(30)
    )  

    CREATE TABLE product 
    (
         pid int, 
         pname varchar(20), 
         color varchar(30)
    )

    CREATE TABLE catalog 
    (
         sid int, 
         pid int, 
         cost int
    )  

    INSERT INTO suppliers
      (sid, sname,address)
    VALUES
      (1, "name1","address1"),
      (2, "name2","address2");
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6303)

Comment: You haven't ended your statements; you need to do so. Use a semi-colon (`;`) (or more to the point post the code that you're actually using and remove the new-line between the end of your statements and the `//`)

Comment: add this INSERT what the wnd of the code

Comment: give me please correct SQL Fiddle

Comment: I found that 
    INSERT INTO suppliers
          (sid, sname,address)
        VALUES
          (1, "name1","address1"),
          (2, "name2","address2");  
is a mysql syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, your INSERT statement will probably fail in Oracle (though this is not the reason why you are getting ORA-00922)

Change it to:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO suppliers(sid, sname,address) VALUES (1, 'name1','address1')
  INTO suppliers(sid, sname,address) VALUES (2, 'name2','address2')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```